# C# get groups that a user is a member of in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm not a programmer by nature so I apologize in advance :) I'm using the code snippets from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#39 and it has been really helpful. I'm using his method for getting user group memberships and it requires his `AttributeValuesMultiString` method as well. I don't have any syntax errors but when I call the `Groups` method via `Groups("username", true)` I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.DirectoryServices.dll

I have done some digging but nothing seems to really answer why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question body so this can be useful to others in the future -- if that link goes down this question will make no sense.

Comment: use PrincipalContext instead it's smaller easier code to manage here is an example for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962539/how-to-get-a-list-of-groups-in-an-active-directory-group

Comment: your welcome and I am glad that you were open to looking at this from another point of view `+1` for you as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

    if(user != null)
    {
       // get the user's groups
       var groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

       foreach(GroupPrincipal group in groups)
       {
           // do whatever you need to do with those groups
       }
    }

}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: I agree S.DS.AM is simpler - when it works.  But be aware that it has bugs that Microsoft seems unable / unwilling to fix: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/748790/userprincipal-current-throws-invalidcastexception

Comment: I always come back to having inconsistent issues with the AccountManagement DLL. It's a nightmare.

Comment: @marc-s What if you want the groups that ARE NOT authorisation groups

Comment: @JsonStatham: On the user object, there is another function called user.GetGroups(). Maybe thats what you were looking for.