# Why the primary group of Local Administrators appears as Domain Users {S-1-5-21-<domain>-513}

Tags: c#, windows, acl, fileinfo, group

I have a text file that the Local Administrator is the owner of the file.
When I am running the following code:

```
public static void CheckPermissions(string filePath)
{
    FileSecurity acl = new FileInfo(filePath).GetAccessControl();
    IdentityReference group = acl.GetGroup(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
    IdentityReference owner = acl.GetOwner(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
}
```

It shows:

```
group = {S-1-5-21-<domain>-513}  // DOMAIN_USERS group
owner = {S-1-5-21-<domain>-500}  // Local Administrator
```

The `GetGroup` function [according to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.getgroup?view=netframework-4.8#system-security-accesscontrol-objectsecurity-getgroup(system-type)):

> Gets the primary group associated with the specified owner.

But the primary group associated to the local administrator is `Domain Users` ?

**EDIT:**
When I checked with the GUI it shows two groups:
[image]

Comment: Okay, so you say that the primary group associated with the local administrator is domain users. You say that, when you run the function on a file owned by the local administrator, it tells you (via security identifiers) that the owner of the file is the local administrator, and the corresponding group is domain users. *How is that not exactly what should happen*? What were you expecting to happen instead, and why?

Comment: Anyway, as far as I can tell the question is purely about how Windows conveys this information, and not about the code used to retrieve it. Please try https://superuser.com instead.

Comment: Because when I am looking on the groups I only have two groups `Administrators` and `SYSTEM`.

Comment: thissid (with 513 rid) present in workstation also and here it named *None*. all users in this group

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751176/c-sharp-get-groups-that-a-user-is-a-member-of-in-active-directory) question instead of asking a programming question on Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confused with the terms.

The `GetGroup` function [according to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.getgroup?view=netframework-4.8#system-security-accesscontrol-objectsecurity-getgroup(system-type)):

```
Gets the primary group associated with the specified owner.
```

The `GetOwner` function [according to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.getowner?view=net-6.0):

```
Gets the owner associated with the specified primary group.
```

So it seems that nothing was wrong with the question.
Just need to understand what meaning of the functions.
For example, the `GetGroup` gets the primary group **associated with the specified owner**.

So if the owner is for example the local administrators **group**, then the owner will be `SYSTEM` and you will get:

```
Group: SYSTEM   {S-1-5-18}  
Owner: Built In Administrators: {S-1-5-32-544}
```

The primary group can't be seen through the GUI Windows. To change it, you need to use `SetGroup`.